# Altium Bus on multiple sheets - pins without connection

Tags: altium

I am running into an interesting problem:

- SoC connected to an eMMC memory
- Data bus width: 8
- SoC provides 2 x 4 data lines

  - 4 data lines by default, additional 4 are multiplexed on SPI pins

The SoC was devided into lots of different sub-groups. 4 of the data lines are on sheet A, the other 4 on sheet B. I tried to connect the sheets using a bus and ports in a hierarchical design.
[image: Hierarchical design with a bus on two sheets, connected by ports through a top sheet]

In the PCB document, when selecting the bus in the Nets, all pins are highlighted as expected (8 on the eMMC, 8 pullup resistors, 8 on the SoC).
But somehow the four pins on the seperate sheet are only highlighted. They are not connected. (In the zoomed section, the selection was removed and one of the pins nets highlighted to show there is no air wire/connection shown).
[image: All pins are highlighted correctly, but pins from sheet A have no connection]

I am pretty sure something is messed up here, but I don't see what this could be. Maybe you guys know?

Comment: Do keep in mind that buses are ONLY for graphical purposes - they don't really _connect_ stuff. As such, you need to ensure that your net labels are transferred through the hierarchy.

Comment: You can find the settings for net name hierarchy in the project options BTW.